# Sort files by last edited after finding them in a specific directory?

Tags: bash

I'm looking to combine `find . -mtime 0`

and `ls -lt`

To find all files modified in the last day in the current working directory, sorted by last modification date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want command substitution which is done with `$(command)`.  It takes the output of a command and allows you to use it as command line arguments for another command:

```
ls -lt $(find . -mtime 0)
```